# Can we find such a monotone function?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Can we find a monotone function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ whose discontinuity set is exactly the set $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$? Or can we prove that such a function does not exist?